# Assign Elements from Array clockwise to container based on boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, javascript-objects

I'm building a visual card game and need to seat the players around the table.
The player's ID which also has the boolean of "pov" set to "true" should always be assigned to the bottom container (in _seats). Afterwards the players ID's should be arranged clockwise around the table.

Also the game can be played by 2 to 4 players, which results in fewer seats and different settings at the table:

2 Players: Seat Bottom, Seat Left
3 Players: Seat Bottom, Seat Left, Seat Right
4 Players: Seat Bottom, Seat Left, Seat Top, Seat Right

I came up with a solution that works, but is terribly long and uses way to many nested statements. How can I write this in a better way? Thanks a lot!

This is the players array that is passed in the function:

```
let players =
    [{ name: "Player2", id: 1, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player3", id: 2, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player4", id: 3, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player1", id: 4, admin: true, pov: true, curDealer: false, }]
```

This object holds the final positions of the assigned player Id's

```
    _seats = {
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0
    };
```

This is my working solution:

```
 renderPlayersAtTable(arr) {

        var seatCount = arr.length;

        arr.forEach(player => {
            if (player.pov === true) {
                this._seats.bottom = player.id

                if (seatCount === 4) {

                    switch (player.id) {
                        case 4:
                            this._seats.right = 3;
                            this._seats.top = 2;
                            this._seats.left = 1;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            this._seats.right = 2;
                            this._seats.top = 1;
                            this._seats.left = 4;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            this._seats.right = 1;
                            this._seats.top = 4;
                            this._seats.left = 3;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            this._seats.right = 4;
                            this._seats.top = 3;
                            this._seats.left = 2;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (seatCount === 3) {

                    switch (player.id) {

                        case 3:
                            this._seats.right = 2;
                            this._seats.left = 1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            this._seats.right = 1;
                            this._seats.left = 3;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            this._seats.right = 3;
                            this._seats.left = 2;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (seatCount === 2) {

                    switch (player.id) {

                        case 2:
                            this._seats.left = 1
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            this._seats.left = 2
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        })



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always put into data structures and objects what you can...  Towards that end, `seatingChart` has been added to represent the variations in seating based on the number of players.  Since arrays are zero based in javascript, the first list in `seatingChart`, representing 0 players, is empty.

The other critical element is the introduction of array rotation through modulus indexing.  To walk an entire array, but starting in the middle somewhere, is a matter of looping from 0 to the length of the array, but adding the starting element and then applying the modulus of the array length.  Eg, let's say for an array of 0 - 4 elements, you wish to begin at element 3. Then, using modulus, we can calculate the desired indexes thusly...

- i = 0, index = ( i + 3 ) % 5 which is 3 % 5 = 3.
- i = 1, index = ( i + 3 ) % 5 which is 4 % 5 = 4.
- i = 2, index = ( i + 3 ) % 5 which is 5 % 5 = 0.
- i = 3, index = ( i + 3 ) % 5 which is 6 % 5 = 1.
- i = 4, index = ( i + 3 ) % 5 which is 7 % 5 = 2.

Notice how the `index` value sequence is `3, 4, 0, 1, 2` which traverses the entire array, but starts at 3.

This basic concept is used in the `for` loop below to begin with the POV player, aligning that player in the first seat (which in `seatingChart` is always `bottom`) and continuing to walk the player array to place the remaining players accordingly...

```js
let players = [
    { name: "Player1", id: 1, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player2", id: 2, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player3", id: 3, admin: false, pov: false, curDealer: false, },
    { name: "Player4", id: 4, admin: true, pov: true, curDealer: false, }
];
    
seatingChart = [
  [],
  ['bottom'],
  ['bottom', 'top'],
  ['bottom', 'left', 'right'],
  ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right']
];

let _seating = {};

let povPlayerIndex = players.findIndex( p => p.pov );

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ) {
  povAdjust = ( i + povPlayerIndex ) % players.length;
  _seating[ seatingChart[ players.length ][ i ] ] = players[ povAdjust ].id; 
};

console.log( _seating );
```

Of course, your code is more readily understandable, but this code is more flexible (ie, it's easier to add more players and seats, because it's a simple matter of data adjustments) albeit at the expense of looking at it in the future and having to walk it through the debugger to remind yourself how it works...

Comment: This is awesome! Yes, my version might be readable, but I knew it was a nightmare from a functional standpoint. At the moment this was all I came up with :) thank you so much!